# INSERTAR EN TABLA MYSQL RESULTADOS DE UNA SUMA EN PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

tengo la siguiente duda, yo realizo la siguiente consulta sql en un php, donde me calcula el promedio de las calificaciones y me la muestra en php, mi consulta es, ese resultado puedo insertarlo en  una tabla de mysql

Aquí muestro una parte de la sentencia utilizada.

```
<?php
    $rownumber=0;
    while($rowedit = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)){
        $rownumber++;
        $alumna = $rowedit["alumna"];
        $ori_prom_1 = $rowedit["ori_prom_1"];
        $ori_prom_2 = $rowedit["ori_prom_2"];
        $ori_1 = $rowedit["ori_1"];
        $ori_2 = $rowedit["ori_2"];
        $ori_p = padZero (round(($ori_1+$ori_2)/2));
        $ori_70 = number_format(round(($ori_1+$ori_2)/2)*0.70,1);
        $ori_pl = $rowedit["ori_pl"];
        $ori_30 = number_format(round($ori_pl)*0.30,1);
        $ori_prom = padZero (round(($ori_70+$ori_30)));
        $ori_prom_ano = padZero (round(($ori_prom_1+$ori_prom_2+$ori_prom)/3));
?>
        <tr>
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $rownumber; ?></td>
        <td id="alumna:<?php echo $rownumber; ?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $alumna; ?></td>
        <td id="ori_prom_1:<?php echo $rownumber; ?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $ori_prom_1; ?></td>
        <td id="ori_prom_2:<?php echo $rownumber; ?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $ori_prom_2; ?></td>
        <td id="ori_1:<?php echo $rownumber; ?>" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $ori_1; ?></td>
        <td id="ori_2:<?php echo $rownumber; ?>" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $ori_2; ?></td>
        <td id="ori_p:<?php echo $rownumber; ?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $ori_p; ?></td>
        <td id="ori_70:<?php echo $rownumber; ?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $ori_70; ?></td>
        <td id="ori_pl:<?php echo $rownumber; ?>" contenteditable="true"><?php echo $ori_pl; ?></td>
        <td id="ori_30:<?php echo $rownumber; ?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $ori_30; ?></td>
        <td id="ori_prom:<?php echo $rownumber; ?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $ori_prom; ?></td>
        <td id="ori_prom_ano:<?php echo $rownumber; ?>" contenteditable="false"><?php echo $ori_prom_ano; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Pues sí, claro que puedes. Pero si al final los campos de la tabla que quieres hacer son cálculos a partir de otros... Podrías hacerlos ya cuando guardas los originales, ¿no? No cuando los recorres para mostrarlos. Si no, sería ineficiente porque actualizarías datos cada vez que los muestras y no cuando se cambian.
Además, convendría saber la estructura de la tabla, saber cómo los has insertado / actualizado, etc. Y también comento que podrías hacerlo quizá con un trigger de la propia Base de datos. Hay mucha documentación al respecto

Comment: ok.. Entiendo un poco tu planteamiento y que tendría que adicionarle a las sentencias?

Comment: A ver... sin la estructura de tabla, campos, etc. es difícil contestar. Date cuenta que no has puesto ninguna de las cosas. Pero una actualización típica de base de datos sería `UPDATE tabla SET promedio1 = (campo1+campo2+campo3)/3, promedio2=(campo4+campo5)/2 WHERE id=5', ¿no? Pero lo dicho... si no muestras ni cómo es el SELECT (o más bien los INSERT o UPDATES) de la tabla, ¿cómo te vamos a ayudar?

Comment: "<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `EMG_4B_3`";
$consulta = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if($consulta->num_rows === 0) {
  echo "No hay resultados <br><br><br>";
} else {
?>